# Change color of mat-select after selected

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to set the same color of the mat-select focus after select . How can I do it?

I couldn't find any content about this in the documentation.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

[image]

I want this color to remain even when selected.
After focus lost color need to be same if selected

Comment: you want blue colour right ?

Comment: Which Angular Material version you are using?

Comment: @YongShun 16 latest

Answer (score 0):

```css
::ng-deep .custom-select.mat-focused .mat-select-value {
  color: #YourDesiredColor;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work as I wanted. I updated the question to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: "your color";
}
input.mat-input-element {
  color:  "your color";
}
```

**Plz check below stack blitz code**

[Plz click on this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-object-1dghej?file=app%2Fselect-form-example.css,app%2Fselect-form-example.html,.angular-cli.json)

Comment: It didn't work as I wanted. I updated the question to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular MDC (v16 and above), these are the styles that make the `<mat-select>` with color (label, arrow down, underline ripple).

```scss
.mdc-text-field--filled:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-floating-label, .mdc-text-field--filled:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-floating-label--float-above {
  color: var(--mdc-filled-text-field-focus-label-text-color);
}

.mdc-line-ripple--active::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-focused .mat-mdc-select-arrow {
  color: var(--mat-select-focused-arrow-color);
}
```

Hence, you need to overwrite the default style by adding to the root stylesheet (*styles.scss*) or Material theme stylesheet (*theme.scss*)

```scss
.mdc-floating-label--float-above {
  color: var(--mdc-filled-text-field-focus-label-text-color) !important;
}

.mdc-line-ripple::after {
  transform: scaleX(1) !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.mat-mdc-select-arrow {
  color: var(--mat-select-focused-arrow-color) !important;
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d9ssyx?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)